# specific issue getting component- chip's jQuery to function properly in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, components, materialize

I have been beating my head against this for a day and a half now.  I think I'm close though!  I have two issues that I've searched high and low for.  Broadly, I am trying to use Materialize within rails to use their "chips" component.  It's seemingly most advanced option uses jQuery to auto-complete a search... once enter is hit it becomes a "chip."  http://materializecss.com/chips.html

I finally got jQuery working by creating a users.js file which is supposed to allow me to just toss in jQuery calls to be reflected in my html view.  Once I got this working, I tried to delete the portions of the code I didn't need to better identify what's doing what...  I did this in codepen.  https://codepen.io/robmatthews/pen/XgyERE

**HTML**

```
<div class="testing">    
    <div class="chips chips-initial"></div>
    <div class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>
    <div class="chips chips-autocomplete"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{
      tag: 'Apple',
      }, {
      tag: 'Microsoft',
      }, {
      tag: 'Google',
    }],
});

$('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
});

$('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
autocompleteOptions: {
  data: {
    'Apple': null,
    'Microsoft': null,
    'Google': null
  },
  limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 1
    }
  });

});
```

Once I got this working (note its the code from the materialize docs plus the document initialization that I assume you need... maybe you don't?  The only part that has only worked for me in within the doc's example though is, of course, the one I want to use.  On the doc's site, the auto-complete jQuery works... it doesn't in codepen... I have no idea why.  I assume I need to add dropdown somewhere because I see that in inspect?? No idea.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  Here's what my appplication.js file includes with the users folder being positioned here: assets/javascripts/users

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require_tree ./users/
```

This is only part of my problem.  My next part will surely be when I am trying to modify the data object to serve up dynamic auto-fill options based on all of the existing users names being searched for! but I'll hold off on that until I get there.  Thanks in advance! can't wait to figure out what my issue is...

Comment: Rats... still cornfused. Something isn't firing as codepen and my code are the same with different outputs. It's gotta be something codepen is preloaded with that I'm forgetting but I feel like if anything, I'm adding including too many scripts... etc. Ahhh when I get home I'll edit in my scsss file that imports requirements